# Android getView() called multiple times after listview height change

Tags: android, android-listview

so i have this listview, with the height of **fillparent** , and mainly it's taking half the size of the screen, but afterwards i need to change the parent layout of this listview. Here i start to notice that the app is freakeshly laging, after some diagnostic i understand that the **getView()** from the adapter is called so many times,

PS: i had this issue at fist when the listview height was at **wrapcontent**, changing it to **fillparent** solved the issue, but came again with the height change,

please if anyone has any clue about this, it would be much appreciated,
thanks all

Comment: The method getView() is called for each row of your listView, thus it may be called numerous times. Please post some code.

Comment: +1, please add your code so we can check it for common mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys, i got my mistake, 
when i try to change the height of its parent, i mistakly did
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.**WRAP_CONTENT**, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.**WRAP_CONTENT**);

after changing it to FILL_PARENT, the problem went away
thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you think your app is lagging due to getView() method, you should try optimizing it. Android system keeps a pool of objects which you can reuse, those are given as a convertView parameter.

```
@Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             if (convertView == null) {
              LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
             }

             // asign correct values to your items - example:

             TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
             text.setText(values.get(position));

             //

            return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful also for an unrelated problem, but i detected my mistake